# Can I find out on which website I got my Litoshi address?

Tags: wallet, blockchain.info

I can't remember where I got my Litoshi address. Is there a way I can find it because boxlit transferred my litoshis already?

I saw the transaction through block.io. I don't think I got it there (block.io). I did not write it down because I always save my username and password in websites I register and sign, but the problem is, I can't remember what website.

Comment: TIL about *litoshi*: A litoshi is to a litecoin, as a satoshi is to bitcoin.

Answer (score 10):

Look at a list of Litecoin web wallets to see if any one them sound familiar to you:

- LiteVault - Online Litecoin Wallet; private keys encrypted locally
- Hive Web Wallet - Online BTC/LTC wallet; private keys encrypted locally
- Liteaddress.org - Litecoin address generation tools (BIP38)
- Reddit LiteTip Bot - Give and receive Litecoin tips from reddit users
- Coinkite - Coinkite is a web wallet with merchant services, Point-of-Sale 
  terminals and debit cards.
- CoinWallet.co - Online wallet
- Harborly - Online wallet that can be linked with any US bank account
- HolyTransaction - Online wallet, multi-currency support
- Celery - Online wallet
- Cryptonator - Multi coin wallet

https://litecoin.info/Category:Services#Wallet_services

If you are able to locate your account, please send your LTC to an offline wallet with a strong password that you do not use on multiple sites.

Web wallets are not the most secure and your practice of reusing passwords on many websites is a horrible security practice.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your browser, you should be able to find the site by looking at your list of saved usernames and passwords. In Firefox this is especially easy because you can view and sort by date a password was last updated or used, but Google Chrome (and other WebKit browsers) also allows viewing a list of saved credentials.